# Clicking button without uploading file

Tags: html, django, forms

I have an html form that users can upload files but if users clicking directly to submit button without uploading any file django gives an error. How can I control this problem?

## upload.html

```
    <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type= "file" name ="docfile" multiple/>

        <button id="yukle" type="submit" value="Upload">
            <img src="/static/img/upload.png" width=28 height=30 alt="Yükle"/>
        </button>
    </form>
```

## views.py

```
def SenetList(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            dosya_tipi = "Senet"
            context = upload(request.FILES.getlist('docfile'),form, dosya_tipi)
            return render(request, 'operations/upload.html', context)
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'operations/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

## forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
    )
```

I gave an error like this:

> ValueError at /upload/senet
>
> The view operations.views.SenetList didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: is this template before rendering or after rendering ?

Comment: I can't understand your question exactly. Can you explain it? @Moha369

Comment: before rendering : `{{ form }}`, after rendering : `{{<form method = "POST"> ... </form>}}`

Comment: It is before rendering i would say, look at csrf stuff

Comment: if you create a form in HTML then why creating a form in `forms.py` ? or why creating html if you have a python form ?

Answer (score 0):

If method is post and form is not valid you return None implicitly. This causes the error. Implement a response for method post with invalid  form

Comment: if its not valid it would not even be submitted

Comment: Well... cannot test now being on my mobile, but in upload.html not the given form is rendered, but a hand coded form not exactly matching the server side validation: no required, multiple file field in template, but not in form.

Comment: As in general you cannot say an invalid form is not submitted, mind server side validation.

Comment: you can try to submit a not valid form :)

Comment: ask yourself why there is a form.is_valid method in django ;) client-side validation is not the only animal you need to care about ... further readings: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: I don't know, yes correct you have a point, but the template denies to send a field if its missing and required

Comment: Yep, but the input tag does not have a required attribute, since its not rendered using the django form.